# How to customize a table for label printing with reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to make the label print to PDF from reportlab by python 3.6, and I checked the reportlab for tables' usage. All of the methods are regular form.

I want to merge the cell to realize the final effect as follows.
<> contains records from database.
[My label requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWVh4.png)
By "Span" method, I got the tables here:
When I met the last rows, I cannot split it. Because I use 0.5cm x16, 0.5cmx11 to format the table. Now, should I change it to 0.25 cmx32, 0.25cm x 22? It must be a mass work.
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdj0e.png)

Does anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem? I need a direction. Thanks.
* If simply draw line and output text, I cannot realize the align,valign, wrap etc.

My codes are here:

```html
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4,cm
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
 
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("LabelTest.pdf", pagesize=A4)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []
 
data= [['1', '', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '13', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['4','', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['5', '', '','','','','','','7','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['6', '', '','','','','','','7','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['7', '', '','','','','','','7','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['8', '', '','','','','','','7','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['9', '', '','','','','7','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['', '', '','','','','','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'],
       ['', '', '','','','','','8','9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']]


t=Table(data,16*[0.5*cm], 11*[0.5*cm],)

t.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
    ('SPAN',(-4,0),(-1,3)),   # Right corner for logo image
    ('SPAN',(0,0),(-5,2)),    # First two rows for product des and surface
    ('SPAN',(0,3),(-5,3)),    # Third row for product requirements
    ('SPAN',(0,4),(5,7)),     # For product picture
    ('SPAN',(6,3),(-1,6)),    # Description and size
    ('SPAN',(6,4),(-1,7)),    # For mat'l no.
    ('SPAN',(0,8),(5,-1)),    # EAN-13
    ]))


elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

---

Currently, I find a solution to make it by myself, maybe it is not the best one, but it really helps a lot.

```html
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4,cm
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
 
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("ex09_1-ReyherTable.pdf", pagesize=A4)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []
 
data0= [['1','9']]
t0=Table(data0,colWidths=[6*cm,2*cm],rowHeights=[2*cm])
t0.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),   
    ]))


data1= [['2','9']]
t1=Table(data1,colWidths=[3*cm,5*cm],rowHeights=[2*cm])
t1.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),   
    ]))

data2= [['3','4','5'],
        ['4','5','6'],]
t2=Table(data2,colWidths=[3*cm,2.5*cm,2.5*cm],rowHeights=2*[0.75*cm])
t2.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
    ('SPAN',(0,0),(0,-1)),
    ('SPAN',(-1,0),(-1,-1)),
    ]))

elements.append(t0)
elements.append(t1)
elements.append(t2)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```